# Validate beginning of stream in Reactor Flux

Tags: java, project-reactor

Using Reactor, I'm trying to validate the beginning of a cold Flux stream and then become a pass-through.

For example, say I need to validate the first N elements. If (and only if) it passes, these and further elements are forwarded. If it fails, only an error is emitted.

This is what I have so far. It works, but is there a better or more correct way to do this? I was tempted to implement my own operator, but I'm told it's complicated and not recommended.

```
flux
.bufferUntil(new Predicate<>() {
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean test(T next) {
        return ++count >= N;
    }
})
// Zip with index to know the first element
.zipWith(Flux.<Integer, Integer>generate(() -> 0, (cur, s) -> {
    s.next(cur);
    return cur + 1;
}))
.map(t -> {
    if (t.getT2() == 0 && !validate(t.getT1()))
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid");
    return t.getT1();
})
// Flatten buffered elements
.flatMapIterable(identity())
```

I could have used `doOnNext` instead of the second `map` since it doesn't map anything, but I'm not sure it's an acceptable use of the peek methods.

I could also have used a stateful mapper in the second `map` to run only once instead of zipping with index, I guess that's acceptable since I'm already using a stateful predicate...

Comment: By reading your question, I *assume* that you're working with **hot** flux. But I need to be sure : are you working with a *hot* or a *cold* datasource ?

Comment: @amanin It's actually a cold flux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement sounds interesting! We have `switchOnFirst` which could be useful for validating the first element. But if you have N number of elements to validate, we can try something like this.

Here I assume that I have to validate the first 5 elements which should be <= 5. Then it is a valid stream. Otherwise we would simply throw error saying validation failed.

```
Flux<Integer> integerFlux = Flux.range(1, 10).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));

integerFlux
        .buffer(5)
        .switchOnFirst((signal, flux) -> {
            //first 5 elements are <= 5, then it is a valid stream
            return signal.get().stream().allMatch(i -> i <= 5) ? flux : Flux.error(new RuntimeException("validation failed"));
        })
        .flatMapIterable(Function.identity())
        .subscribe(System.out::println,
                System.out::println);
```

However this approach is not good as it keeps collecting 5 elements every time even after the first validation is done which we might not want.

To avoid buffering N elements after the validation, we can use `bufferUntil`. Once we had collected the first N elements and validated, it would just pass the 1 element as and when it receives to the downstream.

```
AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(1);
integerFlux
        .bufferUntil(i -> {
            if(atomicInteger.get() < 5){
                atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        })
        .switchOnFirst((signal, flux) -> {
            return signal.get().stream().allMatch(i -> i <= 5) ? flux : Flux.error(new RuntimeException("validation failed"));
        })
        .flatMapIterable(Function.identity())
        .subscribe(System.out::println,
                   System.out::println);
```

Comment: Took me long enough! Your suggestion was very useful in the beginning, but requirements got more complicated and we ended up implementing our own thing. It caused more problems though, so we're now working towards removing the requirement :')